# how to search an element in a list using python?

Tags: python, list, search

I created a function that would delete elements from a text file. I now want to make sure that the element the user wants to delete is actually in the file. However, now no matter if the element is actually in the list or not it always prints "Student was not found" and idk why... Could somoene explain to me?

This is my code:

```
def delete_a_record(filename):

    x=input("Remove Student's Name:")
    y=input("Remove Last Name:")

    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        print(lines)
        if x not in lines and y not in lines:
            print("Student was not found")
        else:
            print("Student was deleted")
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
        for i in lines:
            t=i.split()
            if t[0]!=x and t[1]!=y:
                f.write(i)


    f.close()
    delete_a_record("mytextfile.txt")
```

Comment: `<str> in <list of strs>` will look for an *exact* string match.  That means that you would need the first name on a line by itself, and the last name on a (different) line by itself.  Also beware of newline characters.

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mre]. For example, opening the file is irrelevant, and also badly written (e.g. `f.close()` is not needed), which is distracting. Just provide the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example list of strings and a string I want to find in it:

```
L = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
s = 'a'
```

If I want to find out if `s` is in a string in the list, I can't do `s in L` because `'a'` isn't in the list, `'ab'` is. What I can do though is loop over the list and check if `s` is in any element:

```
any(s in x for x in L)
```

*Assuming the lines in your file are of the form `FirstName LastName OtherInfo`*

Answer (score 0):

What are the lines in your text file? I assume they are formatted like this: "firstname lastname". in that case, your list will look like this: 
`["Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing"]` 
So if you search if 'Monica' or 'Geller', they are not in the file. you need to search for `x + " " + y` or preferably: `f"{x} {y}"`

Answer (score 0):

`.readlines()` reads lines using `.readline()`, that includes the `\n` symbol [in the end of each line](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm).

`input()` does not add `\n` at the end of the input string.

`s in string_list` looks for exact matches, so the input string will not match with any string in the `lines` list.